# How to use setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website i want to have two background images which are changing with setInterval but i don't know how to let this work/

Css:

```
body {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        background-image: url(/Assets/img/image1.jpg), url(/Assets/img/image2.jpg);
        background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    (function () {
        var curImgId = 0;
        var numberOfImages = 2; // Change this to the number of background images
        window.setInterval(function () {
            $('body').css('background-image', 'url(/background' + curImgId + '.jpg)');
            curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
        }, 15 * 1000);
    })();
});
```

I need some help to switch between image1.jpg and image2.jpg using setInterval

**EDIT**

I have change my js to:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('body').toggleClass("/Assets/Style/background/Images1.css", "/Assets/Style/background/Images2.css");
        }, 15000);
    });
```

added two css classes:

Images1.css:

```
body {

    background-image: url(/Assets/img/image1.jpg);
}
```

Images2.css:

```
body {

    background-image: url(/Assets/img/image2.jpg);
}
```

But still my background is not changing

Comment: this is wrong `background-image: url(/Assets/img/image1.jpg), url(/Assets/img/image2.jpg);`, it has to be `background-image: url(/Assets/img/image1.jpg)`. Is the function called every 15s? Just put a console.log in there to see what exactly get's changed. Or use a `debugger` statement

Comment: Where do i put image2.jpg i mean he needs to know to which one he needs te change?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work properly `curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;`

Comment: It should be classes inside, if you use `toggleClass`, not an actual image source

Comment: How do you mean? Can you give me a example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simplify things, I'll have two CSS classes with images you want. Set first class as default and then do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
          $('body').toggleClass('class2');
    }, 15000); 
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QgHcV/2/)

Comment: It must be a 15 secs interval, as OP said, but I think this will work fine. +1

Comment: So by example in class1.css: body {  background-image: url(/Assets/img/image1.jpg); }

Comment: See my Edit, still not working correctly for me but the idea is nice.

Comment: Check out demo - it should help you.

Comment: @JavaAfca Still not changing because you have an error in your syntax `$('body').toggleClass("/Assets/Style/background/Images1.css", "/Assets/Style/background/Images2.css");`. There you have to use the classes you want to change, not the css files. You have to define in your CSS 2 clases like `body.image1 {...} body.image2 {...}` and then change your method call to `$('body').toggleClass('image1', 'image2');`